# Python - Is it possible to automatic retry after "Max retries exceeded with url requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So basically I have a monitor that checks a website changes etc - https://helloworld.com/password - That checks every xx minutes to see if the url has changed or not.

Now after a while it came to an end:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool: Max retries ex
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000001A46BC8
60] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not p
onnection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

Basically my code looks pretty simple that does:

```
def checker(url):
     while True:
            keep_checking = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url))
            if ('password' in keep_checking.url):
                randomtime = random.randint(6, 60)
                log(Fore.WHITE + 'Password still up on %s, retrying in %d secs' % (url, randomtime))
                time.sleep(randomtime)

            else:
                log(Fore.GREEN + '%s\'s Password page is gone!!' % url)
                break
```

So basically how can I retry the script to continue to check after a failure of Max retries etc? I was thinking maybe a solution is to run the method again?

Comment: A try/except block will be necessary to recover from the exception.

Comment: since you're calling this check at regular intervals you could create a cron job that handles the intial task of querying the resource - which should resolve 99.5% of the time. Then replace your 'password page is gone' with code that sends off the task to another regularly scheduled cron job (a batch task used to re-call any missed resources or errors). This way it's all self automated. If you want to keep it more real time, you're on the right track although I suggest using usleep or sleep to avoid overprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J. Owens suggested, you can use a `try`/`except` block to recover from the exception such that if an exception occurs, the `except` block will make the program continue to the beginning of `while` loop.

In order to achieve this, replace:

```
keep_checking = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url))
```

with:

```
keep_checking = None
try:
    keep_checking = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url))
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("Received ConnectionError. Retrying...")
    continue
```

Note that with this code change, the `while` loop will loop forever, so you may want to limit the looping to a specific number of tries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are assembling an url that does not exist based on the error message.

The following line in your code will not yield "password" in the initial url unless a properly assembled url would redirect you to it gracefully, which is doubtful.

```
keep_checking = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url))
```

Given your parameter **url** you may want to provide the full url and not a part with the predefined **https** and **.com**

It is difficult to say if you are trying to run this code as is (as part of a bigger file) or it is modified for pasting here. But in general opening a known url to see if the url changes seems unusual to say and would really only work on pages that gracefully redirect you. In which case you can "just" check for the proper 300 block or 404 response code [300 Response codes](https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/)

Assuming you are trying to see if you are redirected to another page (that requires that the url you are hitting would properly do that and not throw e.g. a 404)

You should e.g. change it to the following

```
keep_checking = requests.get(url)
```

And provide the full URL, e.g. "https://www.hello-world.com/password"
Now if this page does not exist, you may be redirected, then you **may** end up on a page that does not contain password.

There is a wealth of errors that could happen, redirects, timeouts, 404s aso. Given that you may not want to use this for a static webpage you should try to catch a few common issues and not only the error you are seeing right now.